# Why would Python's sys.stdout.write() not work after I index a list obtained from a file object using os.popen?

Tags: python, ajax, file-io

**Updated Updated Question:** 
I have a JQuery $.ajax call that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://website.domain.gov/cgi-bin/myFolder/script.py',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{'lat':'30.5', 'lon':'-80.2'},
    success: function(response){alert(response.data.lat);
                                otherFunction();}
});
```

In script.py, which runs with no errors on its own, I do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, json, cgi
import os

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

d = {}
for k in fs.keys():
    d[k] = fs.getvalue(k)

ilat = d['lat']
ilon = d['lon']
pntstr = ilat + ',' + ilon
my_list = []

#os.chdir('..'); os.chdir('..')
#os.chdir('a_place/where_data/exists')

# If you'd like to run this code, you probably don't have grib files or 'degrib', so another unix command will have to be utilized to open some sort of dummy data

f = os.popen('degrib '+'datafilename '+
             'options '+ pntstr)

out = f.read()

# data has 5 columns, many rows
j = 0
while j < (5*num_lines_to_read):
    my_list.append(out[j+4])
    j += 5

f.close()

#os.chdir('..')  etc until I get back to /cgi-bin/myFolder directory...

x = my_list[0]

result = {}
result['data'] = d
sys.stdout.write('Content-Type: application/json\n\n')
sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result))
sys.stdout.close()
```

NOTE: 'd' is the dummy value and has nothing to do with 'my_list'...for now

When I update the web page I'm developing and try to return 'd' from Python (in the form of an alert), I get a "very helpful" server 500 error.

**I've narrowed the problem down to the "x = my_list[0]" line.** If I instead type "x = my_list", I get no error. sys.stdout.write() *only* stops working when I try to index "my_list". I tried printing the list. It's not empty and contains the expected values with expected types. I get successful output from sys.stdout.write() if I place it *before* "x = my_list[0]". Problem is, I'll eventually use "my_list" to create the output that is written to stdout.

Is there some obscure file I/O thing that I'm missing here?

Comment: -1 "not work" is **not** a description of a software related problem. If you are looking for fortune tellers there's plenty of them, but *not on Stackoverflow*. If you wanted to be helped with your situation you should *describe* it first: what output do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: As I said above, the expected output on my web page is a "dummy value", 'd' (in the form of a Javascript alert). Instead, I get a server 500 error in the Chrome error console. Therefore, I am led to believe that something is causing sys.stdout.write() to "not work". Now that the things you're looking for have been pointed out to you, is there anything else you need to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `my_list[0]` is throwing an exception. Either it isn't a `list`, or whatever it is doesn't support the array operator.

Try examining your web server log files. Try printing `type(my_list)` and `len(my_list)` after you emit the content-type header.

Comment: Hmm type(my_list) gives me <type 'list'> and len(my_list) gives me 145. The list elements are strings, like I want them to be.

I'll have to wait until tomorrow to view the server log files. The boss didn't give me permission to do so. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I ran the Python code sans sys.std.write () and got no errors. Indexing my_list produces no errors then. Very odd.

Comment: New theory. You are throwing an exception in `... more unrelated code ...`. Try to narrow the script down to the smallest possible program that still demonstrates the error.

Comment: I moved the 'stdout' block of code all over the script and narrowed it down to that one line. I tried 'x = my_list', and the 'stdout' block worked fine. Alert popped up on my webpage with the expected output. It's just when I do 'x = my_list[0]' that it doesn't work. I might try to program around it at this point. Maybe some wires are getting crossed in the file input/output and that's confusing the Ajax process? That happened before when I used stdout = subprocess.PIPE, which is why I changed everything to os.popen...

Comment: Okay, you've got my best guesses based  on the limited info you've shared. I suggest that you create the shortest possible program that demonstrates the problem, and copy-paste that program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: There's some more info at the top.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. As I said, without a short, complete test case, there's not much more I can do for you.

Comment: I think the above should work. Script.py will have to go in a cgi-bin. Also, the 'degrib' command is not standard, so you might have to use another unix command to open some dummy data. The data I'm looking at has 5 columns. You can enter whatever value you need for 'num_lines_to_read'. I really, really appreciate this.